# do..while loop not terminating

Tags: c++

I am trying to find if the given number is a perfect square, and if so find the next perfect square for this codewars problem.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

long int findNextSquare(long int sq) {
  // Return the next square if sq if a perfect square, -1 otherwise
  long int k = sq;
  do{
    k++;
    //cout << round(sqrt(k)) << endl;
    //cout << k << endl;
  }while(pow(round(sqrt(k)), 2) != k);
  if(pow(sqrt(sq), 2) == sq)
    return k;
  else
    return -1;
}
```

I am not sure why my loop is not terminating once `k = 144`. Printing out `k` and `round(sqrt(k))` shows that after `k = 144`, it jumps to `626`, for which I also do not know the reason.

Comment: `pow` is not for integers. The floating point returned by `pow` is unlikely exactly equal to `k`

Comment: The square of `int x` is `x*x`, not `pow(x,2)`

Comment: actually I dont know how it plays with `round`, but you are trying to fix the symptoms when you should fix the cause of the issue: Don't use `pow` for integers

Comment: You're approaching this a bit backwards. First determine whether k is a perfect square and, if it is, its root `n`. Then return either `-1` or the square of `n+1`. This is much faster than searching until you find `n+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never try to check if a float is *equal to* an integer (or float) as a looping condition, as there are likely rounding problems (leading to infinite loops). That means you need to reformulate your problem using only integers.

1. Start with the `root` of `sq` in an integer, which can be rounded off.
2. compare the `square` of `root`, `rsq`, with `sq`
3. If it's smaller, increase `root` and compare again
4. If it is the same, `sq` *is* a perfect square (of `root`) and we can return the next square
5. If its bigger, `sq` is *not* a perfect square: return -1.

That could lead to something like:

```
static long next_square(long sq) {
    long root = sqrt(sq);
    long rootSquared = root * root;

    while (rootSquared < sq) {
        root++;
        rootSquared = root * root;
    }
    if (rootSquared == sq) {
        root++;
        return root * root;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter solution, without searching:

```
int next_square(int x)
{
    int root = sqrt(x);
    return root * root != x ? -1 : (root + 1) * (root + 1);
}
```